# Always center text and crop sides, even though resized/opened in smaller viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can automatically center a text, and auto crop the left/right sides from it when resized viewport gets smaller?
So it ALWAYS is centered on screen, no matter how much it goes over the viewport size

I'm thinking css or jquery/javascript. But preferably css only, if possible

HTML:

```
<div class="headline">
<p>============  HERE IS SOME TEXT  ============</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headline {
?
}

.headline p {
?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a particular width to the text element along with `text-align:center` and add `overflow:hidden` to the body. That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried negative margins + nowrap. It works ok for now. Crops left/right + keeps centered

```
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 -500px;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, it might work for you...Try moving the preview pane left and right and see if it suits you :

http://jsfiddle.net/SaM2Z/

You just needed this :

```
#<id-of-div> {
     text-align: center;
     margin : 20px;
     width : 1280px;
}
```

Comment: This does not crop the text

Comment: What do you mean by "crop"?

Comment: Crop as in the meaning of the word. Cut/trim. So the text gets cropped in left/right sides when resizing.. not adjusted, but cropped (and still centered)

Comment: So the text goes off the screen?

Comment: Well, if you set a big size for the <div>, it will "crop" the text if you resize, but it only crops in the right part of the page